# step by step process : create a firewall in a virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Please help me to create a firewall in a virtual machine. I know how to create a firewall of a virtual network. And select firewall from Networking option.

Comment: Hi Priyanka and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is very vague, you don't even mention the OS your VM is running on.  Please edit it adding as much info as possible so people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy and configure Azure Firewall you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/tutorial-firewall-deploy-portal.